# Como source maps são gerados?

Tags: compilação, minificação

Estou desenvolvendo meu próprio pré-processador de CSS, e surgiu a necessidade de gerar [Source Maps](https://web.dev/articles/source-maps). Estes arquivos são "mapas" que mostram partes do código minificado que correspondem ao código fonte original. Eles são parecidos com isso:

```js
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "styles.css",
  "sources": ["styles.scss"],
  "mappings": "AAAA,OAAO,EAAE,CAAC;AACZ",
  "names": []
}
```

Eu procurei na internet como gerar o `mappings` para um arquivo, mas não encontrei nada de como estes códigos são criados, calculados ou definidos.

Como são gerados os `mappings` em um source map a partir do código fonte original e código fonte compilado?